# How to restart automatically data rest api, programming language flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to ask if there is a way to automatically restart the data rest api in flutter, what I want is that the latest data is always updated in my application[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UltIH.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

you can call the function according to your timeframe.

```
Timer? timer;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(hour: 1), (Timer t) {
//your function
});
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```